# How to send dynamic data to popover in angular 5

Tags: angular5

I am used ngx popover. i want to display dynamic data on popover

<

```
div>
 <popover-content #myPopover title="this header can be omitted" 
   placement="right" [closeOnClickOutside]="true">
  <ngx-avatar [name]="subtaskList[i].emp[ind].firstName" 
    size="25"initialsSize="2"></ngx-avatar>
 </popover-content>
 <i [popover]="myPopover"class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming dynamic means data that can change you can bind property (ie. name) to your custom template ngx-avatar and then react to changes using ngOnChanges lifetime hook in NgxAvatarComponent

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    //do something here
}
```